# Knockout - binding like attribute

Tags: knockout.js

It is possible to make binding like

```
<ul data-foreach="myArray">
    <li data-text='title'></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul data-bind-foreach="myArray">
    <li data-bind-text='title'></li>
</ul>
```

instead of

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myArray">
    <li data-bind='text: title'></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You'd need a custom binding provider to do that. I started writing one a while back, not sure if I finished it or not.

Comment: I found [Binding Preprocessing](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/02/24/binding-preprocessing-knockout-3-0/) it's look great

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not gonna like my answer... AFAIK: No, with just Knockout this isn't really an option.

The KO 3.0 plugin [Knockout.Punches](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) may do similar things, you could have a look at that.

Other than that you'd have to write your own extension to KO.

Answer (score 0):

Doing what your asking would require a lot of work. Another option could possibly writing a custom binding handler if your looking for specific functionality for something.

```
<ul data-bind="someBinding: myArray">
    <li data-text='title'></li>
</ul>
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html